# Scroll event triggers, but no scrollTop or offset.top value

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrolltop

Following JS code works, but the values for offset().top and scrollTop(), respectively, remain at 0.

```
$("body, html").scroll(function() {
    // event triggers on scrolling
    var foo = $("body, html").offset().top;
    var bar = $("body, html").scrollTop();

    console.log(foo); // ==> 0 all the time
    console.log(bar); // ==> 0 all the time
});
```

I have the bad feeling that this is somehow associated with CSS overflow, but I can't figure it out.

Here the runnable snippet:

```js
$("body, html").scroll(function() { 
        var bar = $(this).scrollTop(); console.log(bar); 
});
```

```css
html { 
  overflow: auto; 
  height: 100%; 
}

body { 
  overflow: auto; 
  height: 100%; 
  overflow-x: hidden; 
}

div {
  background: #FF9900;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>

  <div style="height: 1000px;">Hi there.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is to do with CSS overflow. You shouldn't explicitly assign an overflow when it's not needed, like on the body and html tags that you have set, the length of the div causes the body to scroll in this case. Setting those overflow:auto properties causes conflict with two scrollbars and can give you some wonky results.

I've setup this basic example similar to yours just for testing and it works. scrollTop changes as it should. offsetTop remains at 0 because the entire body is stationary and you're just scrolling down.

```
<html>
<style>
body { 
  overflow-x: hidden; 
}

div {
  background: #FF9900;
}
</style>

  <head>
  </head>
<body id='body'>
  <div id="test" style="height: 1000px;">Hi there. Click me.</div>
  <script>
    document.getElementById('body').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var scrollthing = document.getElementById('body').scrollTop;
    var scrollthing2 = document.getElementById('body').offsetTop;
        console.log('SCROLLTOP IS' + scrollthing);
        console.log('OFFSETTOP IS' + scrollthing2);     
});
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is actually working, yes. But I used the more compatible version $('body, html'). 
Using Chrome right know, only $('body') works. Why?

Comment: And: In Firefox `$('body')` is **not** working. But the multi-compatible version `$('body, html')` (or vice versa) works just fine.

Comment: @Daniello The body scrolls the html does not. The size of the div is causing the body to "stretch" and therefore you're essentially scrolling up and down the body of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Use window. Body and html are always at the top.

```
$(window).scrollTop()
```

Comment: @PranavCBalan deleted his comments where told me the same. This does not work either. (value: 0)

Comment: try only $(document).scroll(function(){ ... })